# Link doesn't work after deploying site on firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a problem with my website after deploying it through firebase. I have a link in my navigation that takes me to my home page. This link takes me however to the 404 page. All other links work properly. This is the website:
https://okinawa-flatbellytonic.firebaseapp.com

[My home page with popup window my link is in the "Get started"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NUrK.png)

[After i click it shown "....firebaseapp.com/"my url where i want to go ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlwD0.png)

**And that what make him show me  404 page
So my question is obviously is how to make read my link directly without messing with it**

[This photo explain all  please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPWb1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Firebase related issue since you have set an incorrect param.

You will need to put an absolute path that begins with `https://` of your target link.

Comment: Sorry.....  i always end with dum question in stackovereflow you're right Thanks